# Is it possible to retrieve Vector graphics from a SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, pdf, flash

Does anyone know of a way to get a scalable graphic from a swf being played on the client flash player?

Our scenario is that we have a visualisation in a flex .swf that we load data into (through a web service call). Once the data has been loaded we would like to use the resultant image in a PDF.

I can send an image of a DisplayObject back to the server as a PNG and put it into a PDF (using iText), but the png is not scalable and it looks bad in the PDF at different zoom levels.

Anyone found a way around this?

**EDIT:**

To add a bit more clarity. The visualisations are not vector graphics that we import or embed during development, they are charts and trend graphs and custom visualisations created through the flex/flash drawing API, at runtime, based on data retrieved from the server.

Comment: so wait, which question are you asking?  How to get a vector from a swf or how to embed a vector graphic into a pdf?

Comment: How to get a vector from a SWF... I'll worry about the second question once I know the first is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to recreate the graphics using [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/), in combination with the data you have retrieved from the server. The main disadvantage of this approach is that your PDF file will not look exactly the same as your original flex visualization.

Comment: Yes, I love AlivePDF. It has a drawing api, so you can anything you would like directly in the pdf.

Comment: Unfortunately the graphics we are retrieving are quite complex and it's not realistic for us to recreate them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It looks like there isn't a way to do this other than redrawing the visualisation in PDF.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your vector graphic is properly declared in your swf, you should be able to [embed](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html) it like this:

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source='SWFFileName.swf', symbol='symbolName')]
private var _someVector:Class;
```

Comment: Hi @J_A_X. I think you are referring to adding a SWF or image or other resource at development time. See my EDIT in the question - hopefully should give a bit more clarity.

Comment: @dan, Embed works on compile time. So, really what you want is to get the 'vector graphic' (there is no such thing if using the drawing api).  You should look into using ImageSnapshot or Bitmap to get a bitmap of the image.  Of course, it won't be vector and won't be scalable (in a good manner).  Only way to do it would be to reuse the code to draw it directly in the pdf.

Comment: Ok - We are already getting a bitmap(or PNG) of the image. It looks like there's no easy way to do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you were to use a real vector image (svg) or use FXG, it would be much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

check out the following links. *Nicholas

http://memo.tv/drawing_and_exporting_svg_from_flash_as3
http://www.actionscriptdeveloper.co.uk/serializing-and-unserializing-svg-objects-to-arrays-in-actionscript-3/
http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/